# Python:Why my program does not continue anymore?

Tags: python

I am a student using socket to write a simple http protocol ,but my program stuck at the receiver1() method and there is no following replies and the picture has not transmit.Could you please help me to solve this problem?Thank you in advance.
this is my codes:

```
import argparse
import sys

import os

import time

from any_module1_receiver import receiver1
from any_module2_sender import sender1
from any_module2_sender import get_the_files
import threading

global severIp




def input_ip():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="ipaddress")
    parser.add_argument('--ip', action="store", dest="ip", help=' ip_address ', default="127.0.0.1")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    return parser.parse_args()










def identify_the_files_whether_exist():
    if os.path.exists("share"):
        while len(os.listdir("share")) == 0:
            get_the_files()
            time.sleep(0.1)
        get_the_files()

    else:
        get_the_files()
        print(get_the_files())


def getSeverIP(serverip):
    serverIp = serverip
    return serverIp


def main():
    parser = input_ip()
    identify_the_files_whether_exist()
    severip = parser.ip
    getSeverIP(severip)
    print(severip)

    t2 = threading.Thread(target=receiver1(), args=('This is thread 2',))
    t2.start()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=sender1(getSeverIP(severip)), args=('This is thread 1',))
    t1.start()


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the receiver1 module:

```
def receiver1():
    receive_port = 25000
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('', receive_port))
    server_socket.listen(2)
    print('The computer is ready to receive')
    while True:
        connection_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        r_msg = connection_socket.recv(20480)
        with open("xjtlu2.jpg"' "wb') as f:
            f.write(r_msg)
            f.close()
        transmit_done = "done!"
        connection_socket.send(transmit_done.encode())
    server_socket.close()
```

the sender1 module:

```
[def get_the_files():
    paths = \[\]
    if os.path.isdir('share'):
        print("the folder is exist")
        print("seeking files in the folder")
        for filepath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(r'share'):
            for filename in filenames:
                n = 0
                print(filename)
                paths.append(os.path.join(filepath, filename))

    else:
        print('the foleder is not exist, build a new one ')
        os.makedirs("share")
    print(paths)
    return paths


def sender1(tip):
    print("1")
    target_ip2 = tip
    print(target_ip2)
    target_port = 25000
    print(target_port)
    client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((target_ip2, target_port))
    #for x in range(len(get_the_files())+1):
    print(get_the_files()\[0\])
    with open(get_the_files()\[0\], "rb") as f:
        mag = f.read()
    socket.send(mag)
    feedback_1 = client_socket.recv(20480)
    print('From Server:', feedback_1.decode())
    client_socket.close()][1]
```

here is the consol panel
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N399z.png

Comment: That isn't HTTP...

Comment: Hi, this question needs more info and detail like: just saying its not working seems a little low effort.

Comment: this is my trail program, i have more code to write.could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#threading.Thread)

> target should pass in a callable object.
> args is a tuple of arguments used to call the target function.

In your program, the program blocks the `while` loop inside `receiver1`.
So you should make the following changes:

```py
t2 = threading.Thread(target=receiver1)
t2.start()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=sender1, args=(getSeverIP(severip),))
t1.start()
```